# Regex: Match all characters between brackets before equal sign

Tags: regex

I would like to match all names of positional arguments in following example between brackets.

```
function('hello', name='world', arg1 = 300)
```

By doing `(?<=\()[^\)]+` I have managed to select everything between brackets,
but I only would like to match `name` and `arg1`

How can I achieve that by using Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
(?<=,\s)\S+(?=\s*=)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mauMgo/1)

**[Edit]**
An alternative which works with your second example will be:

```
[^(,\s]+(?=\s*=)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very close to what I want.
I should have probably given another example along with the one I have provided.

This is another case:
    function(name='world', arg1=300)

Solution you have provided unfortunately fails since it relies on preceding comma character

Comment: This is the final solution, that works for my cases:
(?<=\(|\s)\S+(?=\s*=)
Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer with an alternative for your second  example. BR.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following. This will create 2 capturing groups, where 1st will have `name` value and 2nd will have `arg` value as per your shown samples.

```
^.*?\((?:'.*?\s)?([^=]*)=.*?,\s+([^=]*)=.*$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/TxNFbK/1)

Above will handle both cases of strings like: `function('hello', name='world', arg1 = 300)` and `function(name='world', arg1=300)` by this regex.

Answer (score 0):

with the following input:

```
function('hello', name='wor=ld', arg1 = 300)
```

@tshiono's answer fails... It would be needed a grammar (and that's above regexps)